# Partition existing table by reference

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-partitioning

Is there any way to partition an existing table by reference?

I have 2 tables (parent and child) that have million rows of data.
I could partition parent using "exchange partitions". But is there a way to partition child table by reference to parent.

Comment: You couldn't partition the parent.  You could create a new, partitioned table and use partition exchange to move the data from the old table to the new table.  Similarly, you could create a new, partitioned child table and move the data from the old child table to the new one.  In either case, you could use the `dbms_redefinition` package to keep either or both tables available during the process at the cost of some additional overhead.

Comment: yes, I've partitioned parent table as you said. but the problem is parent's partition type is by range but the child's partition type is by reference and it doesn't make any sense that I use "exchange partition". suggest that I create a new partitioned child table, now how can i transfer data to new table ?